# Find number of greater element for each element in array

Tags: arrays, stack

This question was asked in interview. I couldn't come with O(N) approach.

> You are given an array of non-negative elements. Find out number of
> greater element than current element on right side.
>
> for Example:-
>
> int[] ar = {13,2,4,1,12,2,6};
>
> output =   {0,3,2,3,0,1,0};
>
> Explanation -
>
> 1. There are no elements that are greater than 13 on right side of 13 so answer is 0.
> 2. there are 3 elements greater than 2 on right side so answer is 2. And So on.

How can I design logic with O(N) approach?

Comment: Something similar to mergesort with inversion count would be O(n log(n)). I don't know about O(n).

Answer (score 2):

you can use nested loop for compare the number array[i] with number array after that without change value of i before all value from array compared.

you can try this code

```
ar = [13,2,4,1,12,2,6]
newArr = []

for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    let count = 0;
    for(let j=i; j < ar.length; j++){
        if(ar[i] < ar[j]) {count += 1;}
    }
    newArr.push(count)
}

console.log("question")
console.log(ar)
console.log("answer");
console.log(newArr)
```

for try that code u can acces online js code compiler https://www.programiz.com/javascript/online-compiler/

good luck!!

Comment: That would be an O(n^2) approach.

Comment: I also able to do this with O(n^2). But I need solution in O(N) or lesser time complexity (if possible)